Can't bring up Raspberry Pi 5 eth0: dmesg shows Could not attach PHY (-19) but journalctl shows new Ethernet device?
Description:
ifconfig only shows lo, wlan0 interfaces on the rpi. Below is a printout from a diagnostic script I created. I'm pretty stumped on what to do from here? If it was actually PHY, NetworkManager wouldn't identify it right?
Some background:

This is on a freshly installed Raspbian instance (latest as of 12/25)
with the latest eeprom version.
I have 4 other devices that work just fine and they were all
initially using the same version. I upgraded just now as an attempt
to resolve the issue.
I already swapped PoE hats with a working device, it's definitely
this device.
I tried running rpi-update already and rebooted.

Bring up attempt:
~ $ sudo ip link set eth0 up
RTNETLINK answers: No such device

Diagnostics:
============================================
1. System Information
--------------------------------------------
Linux node1 6.6.67-v8-16k+ #1833 SMP PREEMPT Fri Dec 20 14:15:46 GMT 2024 aarch64 GNU/Linux
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm

2. Kernel Version
--------------------------------------------
6.6.67-v8-16k+

3. Ethernet Device Detection
--------------------------------------------
0001:01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Raspberry Pi Ltd RP1 PCIe 2.0 South Bridge
[    2.621874] mdio_bus 1f00100000.ethernet-ffffffff: MDIO device at address 1 is missing.
[    2.630020] macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: Cadence GEM rev 0x00070109 at 0x1f00100000 irq 112 (2c:cf:41:1f:39:4c)
[    5.861235] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.300628] macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: Could not attach PHY (-19)

4. PHY Attachment Logs
--------------------------------------------
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x414fd0b1]
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 54.00MHz (phys).
[    1.626689] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3fc00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    6.300628] macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: Could not attach PHY (-19)

5. Device Tree Information
--------------------------------------------
Device tree entry for Ethernet not found.

6. Loaded Kernel Modules
--------------------------------------------
rp1_pio                65536  0
rp1                    49152  1 rp1_pio
rp1_mailbox            49152  1
rp1_adc                49152  0

7. NetworkManager Logs
--------------------------------------------
Nov 19 07:39:38 node1 NetworkManager[618]: <info>  [1732023578.0472] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Nov 19 07:39:38 node1 NetworkManager[618]: <info>  [1732023578.0480] settings: (eth0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Nov 19 07:39:38 node1 NetworkManager[618]: <info>  [1732023578.0480] device (eth0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 25 15:20:06 node1 NetworkManager[610]: <info>  [1735161606.1501] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Dec 25 15:20:06 node1 NetworkManager[610]: <info>  [1735161606.1511] settings: (eth0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Dec 25 15:20:06 node1 NetworkManager[610]: <info>  [1735161606.1511] device (eth0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 25 15:22:37 node1 NetworkManager[628]: <info>  [1735161757.0760] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Dec 25 15:22:37 node1 NetworkManager[628]: <info>  [1735161757.0768] settings: (eth0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Dec 25 15:22:37 node1 NetworkManager[628]: <info>  [1735161757.0768] device (eth0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')

8. Firmware and Bootloader Versions
--------------------------------------------
2024/12/19 11:57:13
version ccf64a4f0756db2e198bb3c32a2c7cde5064a260 (release)
timestamp 1734609433
update-time 1735161714
capabilities 0x0000007f

[all]
BOOT_UART=1
BOOT_ORDER=0xf461
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0


9. GPIO Configuration
--------------------------------------------
gpio command not found. Install wiringpi for GPIO information.

10. Summary of Findings
--------------------------------------------
Detected PHY attachment issue. Check firmware and device tree configurations.


where did you get the image for this freshly installed Raspbian instance? I don't have a Pi 5 (only Pi 4's) ... having said that, I thought the kernel version would be identical (not the kernel itself, but the version) - so how is it you have 6.6.67 - and I thought the uname -r output for PI5 would be 6.6.62+rpt-rpi-2712, not 6.6.67-v8-16k+

Did you not see the warning about rpi-update? Why did you ignore it? Make up your mind what networking system you are using and post details.

@Bravo I got it from Raspberry Pi Imager and you're not wrong, I ran rpi-update to see if it's firmware related before posting online.

@Milliways I ran rpi-update as a last resort, before posting online, because nothing else worked with the regular firmware setup via Raspberry Pi Imager. You really think I missed the huge warning printed when you run rpi-update? How could anyone miss that? NetworkManager is what's running by default on RPI5 Bookworm, what do you mean pick a networking system and stick to it? Why even waste your time typing this? What value did this add?

You would be surprised how many people run rpi-update - it NEVER helps. You have tagged your question with 2 network managers BUT provided no details or network diagnostics

Welcome. "If it was actually PHY, NetworkManager wouldn't identify it right?" -> Not sure what that's supposed to mean, but FYI about "PHY": It's a reference to the physical layer of an interface (see the "OSI model") -- point being that the term can be applied to any interface that has a physical layer (so not virtual things like lo, although I think it may pop up there too in some contexts).   I hate to speculate this implies something may be physically broken.

...Pursuant to that, just because something doesn't work on a certain level doesn't mean it won't on others, so the fact that the problem is reported but the eth device is detected doesn't seem contradictory.
